# Draw CGRect from array of CGPoints on iOS

Tags: ios, uikit, core-graphics, cgrect, cgpoint

I want to draw a rect from an array of [cgpoint](/questions/tagged/cgpoint) objects. I want to crop that rect from an `UIImageView`.

I have done the cropping of the image, and I store all points from the `touchesMoved` delegate method into array. Now I want to draw an area from these stored `CGPoints`.

**Is it possible to draw a `CGRect` from an array of points?**